# updating static resource files in android

Tags: android

I am very new to Android development.

Suppose my application has a few static HTML files that I expect will need frequent updates. Suppose I do not want to publish a new version of my application every time a file changes, but I do want to keep these files up-to-date.

What I imagine I could do, is to write a piece of code within the app to go to a known URL and check for updates every few days. If the updated resources bundle is available, the code will download and unpack it, replacing old files, so that the user will see the most resent content.

Questions I have:
- is such approach a good/bad idea? In other words, are their specific disadvantages to doing update in such manner or is it a commoin practice?
- how can I implement something like that? Service? Is there an existing sample piece of code that I could reuse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the updated resources bundle is available, the code will download and unpack it, replacing old files, so that the user will see the most resent content.

This is fine, except for the "replacing old files" part. Resources are read-only and cannot be modified at runtime. However, you can adjust your code that uses these files to look for your downloaded-and-cached updated files first and use those, falling back to the resources if updates are not available.

> how can I implement something like that?

If your app involves other data synchronization, and you are using something like `SyncManager` for that, just include these files as part of the synchronization work.

Otherwise, [use `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to arrange to get control every so often to check for updates. You will probably need to [use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) to do the actual downloading, as the device will want to fall asleep right away otherwise, if the user is not using the device right then. Use `HttpUrlConnection` or your favorite HTTP wrapper library to download the files to `getFilesDir()` or `getCacheDir()`.